# Query Selector for Specific Text Within a TD

Tags: javascript

A `<td>` contains the following content:

> Candidate Key: ABCDEFG
>
> someemail@gmail.com
>
> 1237567541

And its querySelector is:

```
document.querySelector('#content > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(1) > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(1) > table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(2)')
```

The querySelector returns:

```
<td width="150">
                Candidate Key: ABCDEFG
                <br>someemail@gmail.com
                <br>1237567541          
</td>
```

I need to extract just the email address. I could accomplish this with JavaScript using a substring from the first `<br>` to the second `<br>`. But for my particular use case, I have to be able to accomplish it within the querySelector only. Is there any way to do that? Something like adding `br(0).innerText`?

Comment: @MladenSkrbic `br` is line break, it doesn't contain text

Comment: I should clarify - I'm scraping this from an existing website, I don't get to edit the content. :)

Comment: oke then you can use regex

Comment: After re-reading your question I realised that you wanted to do it without any other JavaScript. If the only function you can use is `document.querySelector` then it isn't possible, as it will always return a DOM Element. Text is not an element, so can't be selected, meaning it also isn't possible to select a substring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the contents of the `td` is consistent then the simplest solution would be:

```js
const email = document.querySelector('td').innerHTML.split('<br>')[1].trim();

console.log(email);
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td width="150">
        Candidate Key: ABCDEFG
        <br>someemail@gmail.com
        <br>1237567541
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, you can't do that directly in the `querySelectorAll` call. It doesn't support regex patterns. You might be able to do it with a "contains" approach, but even that would only get you to the outer `<td>`, because selectors can only grab elements and not the text nodes themselves.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to use Regex. Something like this:

```js
var email = document.querySelector('div').innerHTML.match(/\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}\b/i);
console.log(email);
```

```html
<div>
  Candidate Key: ABCDEFG
  <br>someemail@gmail.com
  <br>1237567541          
</div>
```

So your's will look like this:

```
var email = document.querySelector('#content > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(1) > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(1) > table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(2)').innerHTML.match(/\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}\b/i);
```

Answer (score 0):

thers is more simple => use row / cell

```js
const myTable = document.querySelector('#content table tbody');

let
  txt_1_2 = myTable.rows[1].cells[2].innerHTML,
  eMail   = txt_1_2.split('<br>')[1].trim();
  
  
console.log(eMail);
```

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse;}
td { border: 1px solid grey}
```

```html
<div id="content">
 <table>
  <tbody>
   <tr> <td>0.0</td> <td>0.1</td> <td>0.2</td> </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>1.0</td>
    <td>1.1</td>
    <td>
     Candidate Key: ABCDEFG
     <br>someemail@gmail.com
     <br>1237567541
    </td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
```